# Anti-aliasing not working on Windows

Tags: c++, windows-xp, glut, openframeworks

I'm working on a GLUT based app that needs to run on Windows XP, but as I'm on a Mac, I'm doing most of the coding in Xcode, then switching over to Visual C++ 2008 every once in a while to recompile. It's been working fine, but I just realized that anti-aliasing isn't working on the Windows version.

Here are some screenshots:

Awesome on OS X
[image: Awesome on OS X]

Crappy on Win XP
[image: Crappy on Win XP]

I'm using the GLUT display string "rgb alpha double samples depth".

The shapes aren't actual 3D, they are just triangles:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    ofSetColor(edgeColorFar1.r, edgeColorFar1.g, edgeColorFar1.b);
    glVertex2f(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y);
    ofSetColor(edgeColorNear1.r, edgeColorNear1.g, edgeColorNear1.b);
    glVertex2f(x - _dim, y - _dim);
    glVertex2f(x + _dim, y - _dim);
}
glEnd();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't configured antialiasing to "always off" in the driver settings by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I've got it set to "controlled by application".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting

```
ofEnableSmoothing();
```

in your `setup()` function?